# LWC group record by category

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to group records by a Category value on each record.

Controller

```java
    List<Programs__c> prog = [
    SELECT Id, Name, category__c, subcategory__c
    FROM Programs__c
    WHERE Status__c = 'Active'
    AND category__c= 'Trial'
    ORDER BY category__c,subcategory__c ASC];
```

HTML

```html
    //trying to populate the program records based on their category value?
    <template if:false={noProg} for:each={prog} for:item="category__c">
          {prog.category__c}  // want this to be a header
             <template for:each={prog} for:item="prog">
```

I tried having a list just to return the Category values which gave me the category header but the same program records showed under each category header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to organize your data such that there is nested data. It should look like this:

```js
[
  { "Name": "Category 1",
    "Subcategories": [
      { "Name": "SubCategory 1" },
      { "Name": "SubCategory 2" }
    ]
  },
  { "Name": "Category 2",
    "Subcategories": [
      ...
    ]
  },
  { ... }
]
```

The way you wrote your code, you iterated over `prog` in a nested manner. What follows is a demo.

```js
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Programs__c[] getPrograms() {
  return [SELECT Name, Category__c, Subcategory__c
   FROM Programs__c
   WHERE Status__c = 'Active'
  ];
}
```

---

```js
  categories = [];
  @wire(getPrograms) programWireHandler({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
      // Create a tree of categories
      let root = data.reduce((p, v) => ((p[v.Category__c] = {}), p), {});
      // Create a tree of subcategories
      data.forEach((v) => (root[v.Category__c][v.Subcategory__c] = []));
      // Sort programs into categories and subcategories
      data.forEach((v) => root[v.Category__c][v.Subcategory__c].push(v));
      this.categories = Object.entries(root) // for each category
        .map(([k, v]) => ({
          Name: k, // Name of the category
          Subcategories: Object.entries(v)  // Map each subcategory to a list of programs
            .map(([k2, v2]) => ({ Name: k2, Programs: v2 }))
            // Sort programs within each subcategory
            .sort((a, b) => a.Subcategory__c.localeCompare(b.Subcategory__c)),
        }))
        // then sort each category by name
        .sort((a, b) => a.Category__c.localeCompare(b.Category__c));
    }
    // Error handling omitted
  }
```

Now, we have the desired data structure, we just need to iterate over each part:

```html
<template for:each={categories} for:item="category">
  {category.Name}
  <template for:each={category.Subcategories} for:item="subcategory">
    {subcategory.Name}
    <template for:each={subcategory.Programs} for:item="program">
      {program.Name}
    </template>
  </template>
</template>
```

I've made some assumptions about your field and object names regarding case-sensitivity; make sure the field names match what you expect.

Comment: sfdcfox thank you for the above example and comments. I am testing this now and  I receive an error during the localcompare for the subcategories.  For example there are 5 records where the Category is 'Rent' and the subcategories are numeric and go from 1-5. 1 for the first record and 5 for the last.  In the inspector window I can see it iterates to the last subcategory and then it gives the localcompare error.  There are no null subcategories but they can be the same value.  If you have any suggestion please let me know.  Thank you

Comment: I forgot to mention that it makes it through the first category and is finishing the second category when this happens.

Comment: I determined it made it through the first category when it only had a single record.  When I created another record so that there are 2 records for the first category I received the same error message.

Comment: @Phuc It sounds like a "unable to read localeCompare of undefined" error. If that's the case, make sure you check the field's case-sensitive field name. Aside from that, you can add extra error checking if you know that not all fields are populated.